# Checking if a valid zip code matches a state/city and outputting "unknown" if not in a label

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I've created a program that pulls the corresponding state/city from a database based on the zip code entered, but I need help with outputting an "error" if a non-valid, non-corresponding zip code is entered in the form of the world "Unknown" put in both the state/city labels.

I've tried a bunch of if statements but to no avail.

```
private void BtnLookup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String cnStr;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();

    cnStr = "Data Source=000.00.000.00;Initial Catalog=.  ;User ID=.  ;Password=.  ";

    //Assigns Connection string to the connection object
    cn.ConnectionString = cnStr;
    //Open the connection to the SQL Server
    cn.Open();

    //This statement creates the command object and passes in the SQL statement
    //then associates the command to the cn connection object

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct state, city from tblZipcodes where zip = @ZipCode", cn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ZipCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = txtZip.Text });

    SqlDataReader rdrZip = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdrZip.Read())
    {
        String myString = rdrZip["state"].ToString().Trim();
        String myString2 = rdrZip["city"].ToString().Trim();

        lblState.Text = myString;

        lblCity.Text = myString2;

    }

    cn.Close();
}
```

if a non-valid zip is entered then put unknown in the state/city labels

Comment: If your query returns no results - you will not enter the while loop. So you can initialize the labels with a default value of "Unknown", as one of the options

Comment: You can specify an inline if statement to check the results, if the results are matching as unknown data, then specify the required content for label.

Comment: @User46 Use LINQ to querry to the database instead of using SqlCommand. It would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to check whether your query returns result or not by using [SqlDataReader.HasRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets a value that indicates whether the SqlDataReader contains one or more rows.

And you can implement it like,

```
if (rdrZip.HasRows)
{
    while (rdrZip.Read())
    {
        String myString = rdrZip["state"].ToString().Trim();
        String myString2 = rdrZip["city"].ToString().Trim();

        lblState.Text = myString;    
        lblCity.Text = myString2;

    }
}
else
{
    lblState.Text = "Unknown";    
    lblCity.Text = "Unknown";
}
```